# DomainCollectionView unit test

Tags: wpf, silverlight, unit-testing, mvvm

i have a ModelView its retuen (Users) as ICollectionView , i need to do unit test for (Users) to make sure its have data .

unit test code

```
        UsersViewModel mv = new UsersViewModel();            
        Thread.Sleep(10000);
        Assert.IsTrue(!mv.Users.IsEmpty);
```

the problem is 
 mv.Users.IsEmpty is always true

after some tracing i find its start loding the data after " Assert.IsTrue(!mv.Users.IsEmpty); " Line event if i called the "mv.Users.Refresh"

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found how i make it work in that link

http://www.notesfor.net/post/2010/01/15/How-do-unit-tests-on-RIA-Services.aspx